# Calculating data downloaded by webview for a given url by using webview client?

Tags: android, android-webview, webviewclient

I'm trying to calculate the data downloaded in my `WebView`. Following is my `WebViewClient`

```
WebViewClient mWebViewClient = new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.e(TAG, "init onPageFinished()");
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            Log.e(TAG, "init onPageStarted()");
        }
    };
```

Also to calculate data I'm using:

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
                long currentBytes = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(Process.myUid());
                long totalBytes = currentBytes - previousBytes;
                Log.e(TAG, "Current Bytes ==>   " + totalBytes
                        + "   New Progress ==>   " + newProgress);
            }
        });
```

Following are th Logs:

```
05-06 13:11:11.621: E/TAG(16381): init onPageStarted()
05-06 13:11:11.621: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   0   New Progress ==>   10
05-06 13:11:12.422: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   2736   New Progress ==>   11
05-06 13:11:12.712: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   5743   New Progress ==>   12
05-06 13:11:13.353: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   28084   New Progress ==>   15
05-06 13:11:13.393: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   42576   New Progress ==>   17
05-06 13:11:14.674: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   414446   New Progress ==>   18
05-06 13:11:15.125: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   527120   New Progress ==>   19
05-06 13:11:15.125: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   22
05-06 13:11:15.125: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   24
05-06 13:11:15.145: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   26
05-06 13:11:15.155: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   29
05-06 13:11:15.155: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   31
05-06 13:11:15.175: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   34
05-06 13:11:16.576: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   46
05-06 13:11:17.107: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   51
05-06 13:11:17.127: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   55
05-06 13:11:17.157: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   57
05-06 13:11:17.167: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   59
05-06 13:11:17.177: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   72
05-06 13:11:17.187: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   79
05-06 13:11:17.197: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   81
05-06 13:11:17.197: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   84
05-06 13:11:17.217: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   88
05-06 13:11:17.517: E/TAG(16381): init onPageFinished()
05-06 13:11:17.517: E/TAG(16381): Current Bytes ==>   629186   New Progress ==>   100
```

As we can see that the data bytes gets constant after a certain period of time,I wanna know that what is happening in that time span?`onPageFinished()` is called in the end so definitely this time is not used for rendering the data on the `WebView`. Kindly enlighten me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i also have same requirement,can you tell me how you are getting "previousBytes" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tons of stuff might be happening. The WebView might be getting resources from cache for example, the progress could be reflecting loads of data: URLs, etc..

The `onProgressChanged` API was only intended to drive a progress bar, so the values you get from it should be treated as a 'best guess'.

Comment: Thanks for the response mate,I'm using `mWebView.clearCache(true)` so there is no chance of data to be present in the cache but what i am unable to understand is when all the data is downloaded already why is the `onPageFinished()` not called at that very second?

Comment: `onPageFinished` means WebKit finished loading the main frame (I believe this callback is the equivalent of the JavaScript onLoad event). After the data gets received by the network stack it still needs to be piped into WebKit, which may be busy parsing HTML/CSS, doing layout, running JavaScript etc, so the data got off the network and is in some internal buffer but hasn't been fully consumed.

Comment: If you want to improve your page's performance I suggest using the KitKat WebView (Android 4.4) which supports Chrome DevTools (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging#debugging-webviews). You can use the timeline to gain a lot more insight about what's happening inside of the WebView than you'll be able to using any of the Java callbacks.

Comment: Your answer is very close to what i was thinking from the begining, but i wanna know that is there any documentation from google to support this assumption? That would really help a lot.

Comment: @AndroidWarrior - there aren't any official docs for this. You can look at the code. Taking the Chromium WebView as an example, if you start at http://goo.gl/hBbPco and pull on the thread you'll end up at http://goo.gl/Y6DgRC. A good description of what FrameLoader does is here: http://goo.gl/6cfaCp